# I want to insert new contact into android contacts, that the account is not set

Tags: android, contacts

the account is not set , how to insert a new contact, and after inserted , the contact can be shown in the conatcts' application?

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if you are still looking for answer but it might help others. Try inserting Account Name and Account Type as null, it will insert the contact and also display them in the native contact app.